# How to conditionally remove top home link via local.xml in Magento 1.5.1

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.5

I am trying to do something that seems like it should be simple: add a "Home" link to my top.links on every page *except* the home page (I am using a cms page as my home page). I want to do this entirely in my local.xml if possible.

My thought was to add the link in default

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
             <label>Home</label>
             <url>/</url>
             <title>Home</title>
             <prepare>true</prepare>
             <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/> 
             <position>1</position>
             <liParams/>
             <aParams>class="top-link-home"</aParams>
             <beforeText></beforeText>
             <afterText> / </afterText>
        </action>
     </reference>
</default>
```

and then remove it on cms_index_index

```
<cms_index_index>
   <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/></action>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

but this didn't work out, the Home link shows up everywhere, including on the home page.

What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to do this that doesn't involve hacking core?

**Edit**:
I got the desired behavior by spelling out the whole url, both in my addLink

```
<default>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
             <label>Home</label>
             <url>http://www.mysite.com/</url>
             <title>Home</title>
             <prepare/>
             <urlParams/> 
             <position>1</position>
             <liParams/>
             <aParams>class="top-link-home"</aParams>
             <beforeText></beforeText>
             <afterText> / </afterText>
        </action>
     </reference>
</default>
```

and my removeLinkByUrl

```
<cms_index_index>
   <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url>http://www.mysite.com/</url></action>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

which solves the problem at hand, but doesn't answer my original question. I guess I need to better understand how Magento renders urls with helpers.

Comment: The issue is coming from Magento adding the SID param. It's not rendered, and I don't know why it needs to be there in this context. I'll be looking into this later

Answer (score 1):

Man. I need to look into this (I like the approach you are taking), but if you hardcode your base url and possibly append the non-secure SID param, this should work.

```
<cms_index_index>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url><![CDATA[http://BASE_URL/?___SID=U]]></url></action>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

I don't like this, but it's a start.

Comment: Hi just wondering if you made more headway on this, or if this should be taken as the final solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Heh, haven't looked at this anymore :-)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are in home page then do what you want :

```php
if($this->getIsHomePage()) {  
   echo 'This is Homepage';  
} else {  
   echo 'This is NOT Homepage';
```

or check the identifier name is homepage or not:

```php
$routerName = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getRouteName();  
$ident = Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier();  
if($routerName == 'cms' && $ident == 'home') {  
  echo 'This is Homepage';
} else {  
  echo 'This is NOT Homepage';
}
```

Comment: I mean, sure, but my goal is to write as little php as possible, and consolidate my customizations to a local.xml... this pays dividends in maintainability down the road.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in page.xml:

```
<block type="page/template_links" name="top.links" as="topLinks">
<action method="addLink" translate="label title" name="backhome">
        <label>LABEL</label>
        <url>/</url>
        <title>Home</title>
        <prepare/><urlParams/><position>1</position></action>            
</block>
```

and this in the page custom layout xml

```
...
<reference name="top.links">
    <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url>/</url></action>
</reference>
...
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive in your answer about your codes. Refer:[How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)